# Presto create table with 'with' queries

Tags: sql, presto

typically to create a table in Presto (from existing db tables), I do:

```
create table abc as (
select...
)
```

But to make my code simple, I've broken out subqueries like this:

```
with sub1 as (
select...
),

sub2 as (
select...
),

sub3 as (
select...
)

select
from sub1 join sub2 on ...
          join sub3 on ...
```

Where do I put the create table statement here? The actual query is more complex than the above so I am trying to avoid having to put the subqueries within the main query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible with an INSERT INTO not sure about CREATE TABLE:

`INSERT INTO s1
WITH q1 AS (...)
SELECT * FROM q1`

Maybe you could give this a shot:

`CREATE TABLE s1 as
WITH q1 AS (...)
SELECT * FROM q1`

Comment: @Moosa - Mind specifying what actually worked here? Did the CREATE TABLE ... syntax provided work, or did you have to use INSERT INTO separately? Thanks!

Comment: I had the exact same problem. The CREATE TABLE syntax described above  worked for me. I ran it in Athena V2 on AWS.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Trino as of 09/2022. But the equivalent query with Hive/Spark seems to work

Answer (score 10):

If Strings are concerned, then following works

```
WITH sample AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('strA', 'strB'), ('strC', 'strD'), ('strE', 'strF')) AS account (name, cat)
)

SELECT name, cat from sample;
```

if integers are only concerned values , then following works: -

```
WITH  slab (SNo,Amount) AS (VALUES (1,1000),(2,2000),(3,3000),(4,4000),(5,5000),(6,6000),(7,7000),(8,8000),(9,9000),(10,10000),(11, 11000),(12,12000),(13,13000),(14,14000),(15,15000),(16,16000),(17,17000),(18,18000),(19,19000),(20,20000),(21,21000),(22,22000),(23,23000),(24,24000),(25,25000),(26,26000),(27,27000),(28,28000),(29,29000),(30,30000),(31,31000),(32,32000),(33,33000),(34,34000),(35,35000),(36,36000),(37,37000),(38,38000),(39,39000),(40,40000),(41,41000),(42,42000),(43,43000),(44,44000),(45,45000),(46,46000),(47,47000),(48,48000),(49,49000),(50,50000),(51,51000)
) 
SELECT * FROM slab;
```

Comment: I needed mix these like e.g. "VALUES (1, 'strB'), (2, 'strD'), ..." and that worked fine as well

Answer (score 4):

Syntax is just as if you prepend `create table .. as` to the select. E.g. the following worked for me on Presto 0.170:

```
create table memory.default.a as
with w as (
    select * from (values 1) t(x)
)
select * from w;
```

*(I use experimental `memory` connector so that this is copy-pastable to try it out.)*

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to 'wrap' the entire query like this:

```
create table EXAMPLE as (
with sub1 as (
select ...
),
.......

select 
from sub1....

)
```

Comment: Wrapping the entire query did not work for me

Answer (score -1):

This works

create table answertable as
(
select * from (
WITH
q as ( select findcode from (values 'G463','G464','G465','G466','G467','G468','I64','I694') as concept(findcode) )
select s.*
from table1 s
inner join q on starts_with(s.xxx, q.findcode)
where s.pk  is not null
)
)